# Python: I have a date set generated in Matlab and some columns have a mixture of NaN and float:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example:

```
time
0.5
0.8
NaN
NaN
.
.
.

df["time"] = df.loc[(df["time"].isnull()) , 'time'] == np.nan
```

its converting `NAN` to `nan` but, all the other values since are not `nan` are being converted to 0

How do I correct this?

Comment: Do you just want `df.fillna(np.nan)`

Comment: `df.loc[(df["time"].isnull()) , 'time'] = np.nan`